# SOLVED: No internet connection after configuring ad-hoc interface

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, 19.04, adhoc

Using Ubuntu 19.04 I am trying to connect to an ad-hoc network with my Wi-Fi card (wlo1) and use ethernet (eno2) for access to the internet.
The ethernet internet connection works fine on it's own. In order to connect to the Ad-Hoc network my **/etc/network/interfaces** file is as follows:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlo1
iface wlo1 inet static
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
    wireless-channel 1
    wireless-essid AdhocSSID
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Now with the interfaces file like this I can access the Ad-Hoc network correctly, but I can no longer access the internet with ethernet. This is the output of `ifconfig` for the interfaces file above, which suggests to me that the ethernet connection still works somewhat:

```
eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.129  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::9035:712a:baa8:687f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b4:2e:99:39:dc:57  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 30  bytes 7760 (7.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 51  bytes 6147 (6.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0x55300000-55320000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 174  bytes 14210 (14.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 174  bytes 14210 (14.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::aa6d:aaff:fefd:661e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a8:6d:aa:fd:66:1e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8  bytes 336 (336.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 53  bytes 6469 (6.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: I solved my problem by using Ad-Hoc ip addresses in the range 169.254.x.x rather than 192.168.1.x

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Rather than including it in your question itself, you should [post your own answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) about it. (If you can give more details about how you configured that range of IP addresses, that might help more people, but either way, your answer would be valuable.)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. Please don't put the answer inside the question. Use the **Your Answer** window to write your answer. Then after the required wait time, accept your answer as the correct one. This will help others.